# How to efficiently construct a dataframe (pandas) from dictionary

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

The problem is like this:

```
dict = {0:['A', 'B','C'], 1:'D'}
```

I want to transfer into the dataframe:

```
|index|values|
--------------
|  0  |   A  |
--------------
|  0  |   B  |
--------------
|  0  |   C  |
--------------
|  1  |   D  |
--------------
```

So my idea was to tranform the dictionary into list of tuples:

```
dict = [(0,'A'), (0,'B'), (0,'C'), (1,'D')]
```

Then I can create the dataframe i wanted through:

```
pd.Dataframe(dict)
```

For the dictionary transformation, what i have been using was:

create a flatten function for list

```
flatten = lambda x: [y for l in x for y in flatten(l)] if type(x) is list else [x]
```

use list comprehension to structure the list of tuple

```
pd.DataFrame(flatten([[(i,jj) for jj in j] for (i, j) in dict.items()]))
```

Is there a better and more efficient way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 3):

First do not name a `dict` as *dict*

Then we look at the question, I am using `pd.Series` with `stack`

```
pd.Series(d).apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
Out[149]: 
0    A
0    B
0    C
1    D
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, dict should never be named for dictionary.

Comment: Although this approach seems to be slower than my original approach.@Wen